# Note on Ring Homomorphisms of Matrices Rings

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, field-theory

Assume that $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, and let $\mathbb{M}_{t}\left(
\mathbb{F}\right)  $ be the ring of matrices of order $t$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

Does there exist a non-trivial ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{M}_{n+1}\left(
\mathbb{F}\right)  $ to $\mathbb{M}_{n}\left(  \mathbb{F}\right)  $?

Comment: No: there would have to be a non-zero kernel ( for example, decompose $1$ as a sum of $n+1$ mutually orthogonal primitive idempotents in $M_{n+1}.$ At least one of these would have to be sent to $0$ in $M_{n}.$ But $M_{n+1}(\mathbb{F})$ is a simple ring, so has no proper non-zero two-sided ideals.

Answer (score 6):

$M_{n+1}(\mathbb F)$ is simple, so a nontrivial ring homomorphism from $M_{n+1}(\mathbb F)$ is an isomorphism onto its image.  Let $N\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb F)$ be a nilpotent matrix of order $n+1$.  Then the image of $N$ under an isomorphism is also nilpotent of order $n+1$, but $M_n(\mathbb F)$ contains no such elements.

Comment: simple and elegant proof.